# PHP cURL not sending headers (?)

Tags: php, curl, header

I attempted to modify the code I found on this webpage: https://tutorialsclass.com/php-rest-api-get-data-using-curl/

The API I'm using needs two custom headers: Accept-Encodig and x-api-key.

My modified code looks like this:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();

$url = "http://thelinktomyAPI";

$headers = array(
            'Accept-Encoding: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'x-api-key: MyLongAPIKey'
            );

// Set the curl URL option
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'application/json');


// This option will return data as a string instead of direct output
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_data = curl_exec($curl_handle);

if ($curl_data === false)
{
    print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl_handle));
}

curl_close($curl_handle);
print_r($curl_data);
```

So as you can see I'm making my headers visible to make sure I'm actually sending them. What I get shown is a webpage with the following:

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Thu, 02 Dec 2021 08:09:59 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 110 
 Connection: keep-alive
 Location: http://thelinktomyAPI 
 X-Trace-ID:f306fe34-079b-493c-b5db-073e792ec2a1 
 X-Kong-Response-Latency: 0
 Server: kong/2.3.3 302 Found
```

Since the Content-Type is shown as "text/html" it leads me to believe that my headers aren't sent at all, hence I'm not getting any data. I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit** Adding `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` as Professor Abronsius suggested helped!

Comment: try adding another option into the curl config - `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and set `true`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius This helped! I don't understand why but my mind is blown and I'm just so happy I can now actually write the application (since I'm finally getting the data in). Thank you so much!

Comment: a `302` response means the resource is located elsewhere so you instruct curl to follow that redirect and return the response from the actual desired endpoint. You can specify the number of redirects that it will follow if required